# Permutation representations

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I need a source for Permutation representations of general linear groups over finite fields. Can anyone introduce some sources?

Comment: [A question about that topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232757/permutation-representations-of-general-linear-groups-over-finite-fields)